# Is it correct to say "become touched"?

Tags: vocabulary

Is it in any possible way correct to say "become touched"? Example: ...Disappointed that they don't give us attention we desire, we can become touched and perceive even biggest compliments as slights.

Comment: Thanks Yosef! I know, touchy is definitely better, I just wonder if "become touched" makes sense in this context

Comment: No it does not quite make it to say your disappointment made you touched. Unless you mean touched/crazy/paranoid and not just disappointed. Then you became touched (= went crazy) and in that state even a compliment looked like a slight to you based on your exaggerated perception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it reversed. Touched (when it does not mean crazy) means the heart is touched or reached tenderly: I am touched by your sweet gesture.

The word you want may be **touchy**, meaning overly sensitized to feelings. It is something like being grumpy, or unnerved by little things: "*Are always this touchy or just grumpy in the morning?"*

> Tending to take offense with slight cause; oversensitive; easily ignited or exploded [[American Heritage Dictionary, 5th Ed.]](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/touchy)